# What is right view regarding rebirth?

Tags: rebirth, right-view

What is right view regarding rebirth according to the Buddha? Is it:

- a) Rebirth stops after breakup of physical body for all even if
  craving is not eradicated
- b) Rebirth continues eternally after
  breakup of physical body for all even if craving is eradicated
- c)
  Rebirth stops after breakup of physical body if craving is eradicated. Rebirth continues after
  breakup of physical body if craving is not eradicated.
- d) Other?

If possible, please provide sutta references.

Comment: It's not my intention to nit pick, but to point out one of Buddha's great qualities, precision and accuracy in choice of words like no others.  So technically one still has rebirth even all cravings are eradicated, if he still has higher fetters.  However, a last final rebirth will take place in Sudavasa realms exclusively for non-returners as final rebirth.  Your question is well understood tho.  Buddha is the only person who has never misspoken.

Comment: maybe replace "craving" in your question with "fetters" to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Householders, what if just taking [A Safe Bet](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.060.than_en.html)?

Answer (score 1):

- a) False
- b) False
- c) The cause of rebirth is eliminated while one lives when one attains Arahanthship. Hence rebirth does not occur after break up of the body.
- d) For those who haven't eliminated craving, rebirth occurs only at the break up of the body. Keep in mind that the usage of the word 'rebirth' in Buddhism does not imply a soul.
- e) Buddhists usually do not get confused even if you use the word 'death' instead of "break up of the body".

Answer (score 1):

C. http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.002.than.html

"Now from the remainderless fading & cessation of that:

1. **very ignorance (past-defilement/past-cause) comes the cessation of fabrications (past-kamma-becoming/past-cause).**
2. **From the cessation of fabrications comes the cessation of consciousness (present-birth/present appearance of consciousness-aggregate/present suffering/present-effect).** [mano pubbaṅgamā dhammā]
3. From the cessation of consciousness comes the cessation of
   name-&-form (present-birth/present appearance of form-aggregate & feeling-aggregate & perception-aggregate & fabrication-aggregate/present-suffering/present-effect).
4. From the cessation of name-&-form comes the cessation of the six
   sense media (present-suffering/present-effect).
5. From the cessation of the six sense media comes the cessation of
   contact (present-suffering/present-effect).
6. From the cessation of contact comes the cessation of feeling (present-suffering/present-effect).
7. From the cessation of feeling comes the cessation of craving (present-defilement/present-cause).
8. **From the cessation of craving comes the cessation of
   clinging/sustenance (present-defilement/present-cause).**
9. **From the cessation of clinging/sustenance comes the cessation of
   becoming (present-kamma-becoming/present-fabrications/present-cause).**
10. **From the cessation of becoming comes the cessation of birth (future-birth/future-upatti-becoming/future-effect).**
11. From the cessation of birth, then aging & death, sorrow,
     lamentation, pain, distress, & despair all cease (future-effect).

Such is the cessation of this entire mass of stress & suffering."

Answer (score -2):

The right view regarding 'rebirth' (upapannā) according to the Buddha is:

a) Reappearance (upapannā) continues after breakup of the **kaya** (group; collection) for all if craving is not eradicated

b) Reappearance (upapannā) does not continue eternally at the breakup of the kaya if craving is eradicated because the end of craving is The Deathless.

c) Reappearance (upapannā) stops at the breakup of the kaya if craving is eradicated. Reappearance (upapannā) continues after breakup of the kaya if craving is not eradicated.

The word 'kaya' does not mean 'physical body'. The physical body is called 'rupa'. The 'kaya' means the 'collection' of the five aggregates. It is best to not misrepresent or slander the Buddha.

If the word 'death' ('marana') referred to physical death then it would not be a wrong view to say the Buddha ceases to exist after death. But, in Buddhism, it is wrong view to say a Buddha does not exist after death (marana) because a Buddha does not experience 'death'.

> *Friend Yamaka, do not speak thus. Do not misrepresent the Blessed One. It is not good to misrepresent the Blessed One. The Blessed One
>   would not speak thus: ‘A bhikkhu whose taints are destroyed is
>   annihilated and perishes with the breakup of the body and does not
>   exist after death.’ SN 22.85*
>
> ---
>
> *Dhammapada 21. Heedfulness is the path to the Deathless. Heedlessness is the path to death. The heedful die not. The heedless are as if dead
>   already.*